# Why return four lists when using map() with the method .append()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to test the function `map` with the method `append` and got a wrong output.

#### Code

```
numbers = [
    [34, 63, 88, 71, 29], 
    [90, 78, 51, 27, 45], 
    [63, 37, 85, 46, 22], 
    [51, 22, 34, 11, 18]
]

numbers_tmp = []

def mean_append(num_list):
    numbers_tmp.append(sum(num_list) / len(num_list))
    return numbers_tmp

print(list(map(mean_append, numbers)))
```

#### Expected output

```
[57.0, 58.2, 50.6, 27.2]
```

#### Actual output

```
[
    [57.0, 58.2, 50.6, 27.2], 
    [57.0, 58.2, 50.6, 27.2], 
    [57.0, 58.2, 50.6, 27.2], 
    [57.0, 58.2, 50.6, 27.2]
]
```

Comment: Why did you make `numbers_tmp` a global variable, and then ignore its contents in favor of what `map` returns anyway?

Comment: Do **not** use side effects in `map`. Just use a for loop

Answer (score 3):

Built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) works on **each value** in an iterable. So your function should include logic which can be applied to *each sublist*:

```
def mean_calculator(num_list):
    return sum(num_list) / len(num_list)

res = list(map(mean_calculator, numbers))

print(res)

[57.0, 58.2, 50.6, 27.2]
```

Alternatively, you can use [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) from the standard library:

```
from statistics import mean

res = list(map(mean, numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` returns one output object for each object in the input sequence. Your input sequence has 4 objects, so the output has 4 objects. They're all same since your function always returns same `numbers_tmp` *object*. To fix the problem stop using global variables in `map`.

Comment: And side effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [[34, 63, 88, 71, 29], [90, 78, 51, 27, 45], [63, 37, 85, 46, 22], [51, 22, 34, 11, 18]]
def mean_append(num_list):
    return sum(num_list) / len(num_list)

print(list(map(mean_append, numbers)))
```